# Netbeans runs all my projects

Tags: netbeans, projects

I'm using Netbeans 6.5.1 (tomcat 6.0.18 included)

I've developed many webapp projects on netbeans.
I created a contextlistener for each webapp which prints "Hello World! this is <>" in contextInitialized method.

Whenever I click "Run main project" button (or click-right-mouse-button over a project and select "Run") I can see in tomcat's output window all my other projects are running as well.

I mean, when I run a project (any project) I can see that all my webapps call their respective context listener! the worst scenario is when a webapp uses hibernate: each webapp do all the related hibernate initialization work.

Is there any way to run only the project I want?

I already tried closing the other projects but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From what I recall, Netbeans does not always un-deploy your other web applications from the development tomcat server.

To remove the other projects, go to the `Services` (formerly Runtime) tab. Expand the `Servers` group. Right click the Tomcat Server instance and select Start (if it's not already running). Expand the Tomcat Server group--it should list all of the deployed application. Right click each application and select Undeploy.

I'm going from memory so please forgive me if my instructions are off...

Comment: Hi James

Thx, undeploy did the work!

I thought that if I undeploy a webapp in netbeans it could get deleted because when used to use tomcat whithout netbeans and I undeployed an app tomcat deleted all my src files :S

However, I think there should be some other way to say Netbeans to start only the webapp I'm running, isn't it? like some sort of auto-undeploy. Any way, thx for the tip :) I'll use it every day

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a NetBeans bug. You could trying using NB 6.7 RC 3 to see if the problem has been fixed already.

Answer (score 0):

Really strange indeed... I don't think this can be a NetBeans Bug since 6.5 it's an stable version. Please, double check these:

- Did you actually tried to set a main
  project explicitly? (Right click on
  the project and **Set as main
  project**)
- Are you sure that there are no class
  or package dependencies/relations on
  your projects?
- Did you create every single one of
  your web apps with the **new project
  wizard**, or they are actually
  classes within your project?
- You mention that Apache wasn't
  included with your NetBeans. Did you
  installed the app server by yourself?
  If so, you should check your server
  documentation and try to check the
  configuration files.

Comment: Hi rigovides
* Yes, I did set a main project.
* There are not dependencies between any of my webapps projects. Some webapp projects have a dependency with a java application project (a library I created). I think this library isn't the root of the problem, because even when I set as main project any webapp that doesn't use this library, even so all the webapps get to run when running main project :(
* Tomcat was included with netbeans, it was install when netbeans did.
Thx, any other idea?

Comment: Then try undeploying your apps (if they are all-deployed by default) as James Schek suggest; If this doesn't then let's assume it's a NetBeans Bug (-Zian Choy), so try reinstalling NetBeans from scratch, the newer the better and with tomcat included